# SQL Server: return a blank line if the search does not match

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in my SQL Server database that looks like this:

```sql
select * 
from products 
where code in ('0001', '0002', '0003', '0009')
```

This query would return something like this:

```sql
+----+------+-------------+
| id | code | description |
+----+------+-------------+
| 01 | 0001 | CAIXA DE... |
| 02 | 0002 | CAIXA DE... |
| 03 | 0003 | CAIXA DE... |
+----+------+-------------+
```

Note that code 0009 does not match the search, however I would need a blank line to be returned.

Something like this:

```sql
+----+------+-------------+
| id | code | description |
+----+------+-------------+
| 01 | 0001 | CAIXA DE... |
| 02 | 0002 | CAIXA DE... |
| 03 | 0003 | CAIXA DE... |
|    |      |             |
+----+------+-------------+
```

Would it be possible to do something like that, maybe with a procedure, or a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table value constructor to create a table with your desired codes in, then left join to your product table:

```
SELECT  p.Id,
        v.Code,
        p.Description
FROM    (VALUES('0001'), ('0002'), ('0003'), ('0009')) AS v (Code)
        LEFT JOIN Products AS p
            ON p.Code = v.Code;
```

If you need to parameterise this (e.g. if calling from an application), you would need to create a type to store your list of codes:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList (Value VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

*N.B. I tend to go for fairly generic names for table types, for ease of re-use.*

You can then use this type as a parameter, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure @Codes dbo.StringList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  p.Id,
            Code = c.Value,
            p.Description
    FROM    @Codes AS c
            LEFT JOIN Products AS p
                ON p.Code = c.Value;

END
```

Which can be called as follows:

```
DECLARE @codes dbo.StringList;
INSERT @Codes (Value) VALUES('0001'), ('0002'), ('0003'), ('0009');
EXECUTE dbo.YourProcedure @Codes;
```

Comment: My congratulations, this works like a charm, is there any way to prevent him from duplicating the items?

Comment: Prevent who from duplicating the items? Which method are you using, the first or the second?

Comment: yes, I am using the first method, it is bringing multiple times

Comment: Are you adding the same code into the table value constructor multiple times? Or do you perhaps have duplicates in the product table?

Comment: I found the problem, there are duplicate items in my table, but apparently I can't add where

Comment: Yes really the problem was in my table, when adding another condition ```ON p.Code = c.Value and p.deleted <> '*';``` work perfectly

Comment: one more thing, would it be possible to order the results according to what is sought?

Comment: You'd just need to add the required order to the table valued constructor, e.g. `FROM (VALUES(1, '0001'), (2, '0002'), (3, '0003'), (4, '0009')) AS v (SortOrder, Code)` Then you can sort by this new column at the end of the query `ORDER BY v.SortOrder`